# BizTalk 2009 EDI HIPAA 5010A Hotfix/Update

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009, edi, hipaa

I was wondering if anyone could offer any insight as to when an update is going to be released for BizTalk to comply with the 5010A standard, all addendums and errata included.

I've just about exhausted myself with Google and Bing searches and the only thing that I can find is a very vague mention of first quarter 2011 on MSDN, but that timeline has nearly passed with no mention of it again. The BizTalk product team blog stopped blogging early last year and their last mention of 5010 was related to the first hotfix that was released for the original standard, but none of the addendums or errata are handled by that hotfix that I can see.

Maybe I'm missing something, but I'm up to my knees is 5010 development right now and we're getting close to testing across several transaction sets, none of which can be tested without the schemas being up to date.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cumulative update package 2 for BizTalk Server 2009

```
* HIPAA 5010 Errata Schemas included
```

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2497794

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/biztalkediandas2/thread/c61f2983-05f2-45fe-9d82-a10a25bd32f5